# Error "Failed processing Browscap file" python webscraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, urllib3

I am trying to create a program which will access a specific https webpage on my university website in which my semester marks are displayed. I want to scrape the web page to check for changes to when my final marks come out and then send an email to myself (easier than having to check at random throughout the day).

I've never done web scraping before and the site requires login authentication so this problem is probably more complicated than I think but here is what I have so far:

```
import certifi
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib3 as u

url = "https://upnet.up.ac.za/psc/pscsmpra/EMPLOYEE/SA/c/UP_SS_MENU.UP_SS_RESULTS_FL.GBL"
http = u.PoolManager(cert_reqs='CERT_REQUIRED',ca_certs=certifi.where())

try:
    r =    http.request('GET',url,timeout=u.Timeout(connect=1.0, read=2.0))
except u.exceptions.NewConnectionError: 
    print("Connection Failed")

print(r.status)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.data,features="html.parser")

print(soup.prettify())
```

running this code returns the following:

> 200
>
> Failed processing Browscap file. as it could be missing. Please
>   contact your system adminstrator.

If i run r.headers i get this:

> HTTPHeaderDict({'Date': 'Thu, 15 Nov 2018 07:13:27 GMT', 'Server':
>   'Apache', 'Content-Length': '99', 'X-Frame-Options': 'SAMEORIGIN',
>   'Set-Cookie':
>   'appcsmpr08-7007-PORTAL-PSJSESSIONID=5T8WMyIf2lC2ZSBTaf84UZBA-tV9BLAh!631984709;
>   domain=.up.ac.za; path=/; HttpOnly,
>   NSC_wt_dbnqvtqspe=ffffffff8adf14db45525d5f4f58455e445a4a422d6f;expires=Thu,
>   15-Nov-2018 08:09:29 GMT;path=/;httponly,
>   dtCookie=E2152DB7F41B75674D0AE5146876F0EB|UFNDU018MQ; Path=/;
>   Domain=.up.ac.za', 'X-Clacks-Overhead': 'GNU Terry Pratchett',
>   'Content-Type': 'text/plain; charset=UTF-8'}) PS
>   C:\Users\Shaun\Documents\Personal_Projects\markAlert>

I assume that I'm able to connect but I'm uncertain of what is meant by the error above. A google search was no help.

Any help on how to fix this appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

the error came from the server because cannot detect your request user-agent, set it.

```
heads = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:57.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/57.0'}
http = u.PoolManager(headers=heads)
```